# How can I forward Mailer Daemon notifications in Outlook 2000?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, forwarding

I have a rule in Outlook 2000 which states that any incoming message should be forwarded to another adress (The mailaccount is only used to send automatic alerts and notifications of an application, answers to this adress should be forwarded to the admin of this application).
When the application tries to send an eMail to a non existent adress, the resulting Mailer Daemon notification won't be forwarded and the admin of the server will notice this problem very late (if ever).
Is there a way to forward such messages to another adress? The problem seems to be, that Exchange delivers such notifications as "Report" but the rules will only apply to "Messages".

Answer (score 0):

What rule are you using? You might be able to get this to work with 2 rules: one for normal messages, and one where the body contains "failure" (or something similar).

Comment: I'm using the german version of Outlook - I tranlated the rules:

When recieving a mail, forward to <admin>

I also tried:
When recieving a mail, which contains the word "Unzustellbar" (undeliverable) in the subject, forward to <admin>
(As the subject is: "Unzustellbar: <original subject>")

and

When recieving a mail from <system administrator> forward to <admin>

But all three failed. The first rule should have caught them anyway. This is why I suspected that Outlook uses different types of emails like "Message" and "Report". You can see the type of a message in its properties.

Comment: On some email systems, that "undeliverable" text isn't really part of the subject. The email software displays that when it sees a form called "delivery failure."

With that in mind, try again with keywords from the body of the message.